# Migrating from sql server to Oracle varchar length issues

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, varchar, nvarchar

Im facing a strange issue trying to move from sql server to oracle.
in one of my tables i have column defined by `NVARCHAR(255)`
after reading a bit i understod that SQL server is counting characters when oracle count bytes.
So i defined my table in oracle as `VARCHAR(510)` 255*2 = 510
But when using sqlldr to load the data from a tab delimetered text file i get en error indicating some entries had exiceeded the length of this column.
after checking in the sql server using:

```
SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(column))
FROM table
```

i get that the max data length is 510.

I do use Hebrew_CI_AS collationg even though i dont think it changes anything....
I checked in SQL Server also if any of the entries contains TAB but no... so i guess its not a corrupted data....
Any one have an idea?

**EDIT**
After further checkup i've noticed that the issue is due to the data file (in addition to the issue solved by @Justin Cave post.

I have changed the row delimeter to '^' since none of my data contains this character and '|^|' as column delimeter.

creating a control file as follows:

```
load data
infile data.txt "str '^'"
badfile "data_BAD.txt"
discardfile "data_DSC.txt"
into table table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|^|' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
     col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     col4,
     col5,
     col6
)
```

The problem is that my data contain `<CR>` and sqlldr expecting a stream file there for fails on the `<CR>`!!!! i do not want to change the data since its a textual data (error messages for examples).

Comment: One other gotcha you may face: Oracle considers a blank (zero-length) string to be the same as NULL, whereas SQL Server considers them to be different. So if your original SQL Server database has a non-NULL field that contains blanks, you won't be able to migrate this data to the Oracle version (unless you remove the non-NULL constraint in the Oracle version).

Comment: @MusiGenesis thanks for saving me that issue, but i dont see how it solves my issue.... :(

Comment: it doesn't solve your issue - that's why I put it as a comment instead of as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your database character set

```
SELECT parameter, value
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

Assuming that your database character set is AL32UTF8, each character could require up to 4 bytes of storage (though almost every useful character can be represented with at most 3 bytes of storage).  So you could declare your column as `VARCHAR2(1020)` to ensure that you have enough space.

You could also simply use character length semantics.  If you declare your column `VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)`, you'll allocate space for 255 characters regardless of the amount of space that requires.  If you change the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` initialization parameter from the default BYTE to CHAR, you'll change the default so that `VARCHAR2(255)` is interpreted as `VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)` rather than `VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)`.  Note that the 4000-byte limit on a `VARCHAR2` remains even if you are using character length semantics.

If your data contains line breaks, do you need the `TRAILING NULLCOLS` parameter?  That implies that sometimes columns may be omitted from the end of a logical row.  If you combine columns that may be omitted with columns that contain line breaks and data that is not enclosed by at least an optional enclosure character, it's not obvious to me how you would begin to identify where a logical row ended and where it began.  If you don't actually need the `TRAILING NULLCOLS` parameter, you should be able to use the [CONTINUEIF parameter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005509) to combine multiple physical rows into a single logical row.  If you can change the data file format, I'd strongly suggest adding an optional enclosure character.

Comment: A word of warning: "Independently of the maximum length in characters, the length of VARCHAR2 data cannot exceed 4000 bytes." http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i45694. In other words `varchar2(2000 char)` will not hold 2000 characters where each character is three bytes long. The column in OP's question is short enough to not matter.

Comment: @NoamShaish - Added info on combining multiple physical records into a logical record.  In the future, you might want to ask a separate question rather than editing your initial question if you're asking a very different follow-up.  It would probably be cleaner to have one question devoted to VARCHAR2 length issues and one devoted to using SQL*Loader to assemble multiple physical rows into a single logical rows.

Answer (score -1):

The bytes used by an `NVARCHAR` field is equal to two times the number of characters *plus* two (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), so if you make your `VARCHAR` field 512 you may be OK. There's also some indication that some character sets use 4 bytes per character, but I've found no indication that Hebrew is one of these character sets.

Comment: Length bytes are not going to be counted against the defined size of `*char*` strings.